# In Ruby, Does Dividing a String with Backslash Represent Implicit Concatenation?

Tags: ruby, string, format, concatenation

Consider dividing a String in Ruby as follows:

```rb
"Some content "\
"and some more "\
"and the final line."
```

Does the above create three String objects and concatenate them together? Or does Ruby treat that as one string, which is merely visually split by the backslash character for developer convenience (that is, the backslash is not an operand / method) ?

Also, is there a word / term for dividing a string in this way, or is it simply another way to concatenate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Automatic Concatenation of String Literals

Technically, you are creating three string literals, which are then automatically concatenated by the interpreter. This is documented [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings), where is says:

> Adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated by the interpreter..Any combination of adjacent single-quote, double-quote, percent strings will be concatenated as long as a percent-string is not last.

In your specific example, escaping the newlines at the end of each line of code makes them "adjacent" for the purposes of automatic concatenation. It ignores the whitespace between strings, so the following are also logically equivalent to your original example:

```
"Some content "'and some more '"and the final line."
#=> "Some content and some more and the final line."

"Some content " "and some more " "and the final line."
#=> "Some content and some more and the final line."
```

Comment: It should also be noted that automatic interpreter concatenation is massively faster (roughly 479% faster) than all other concatenation methods I benchmarked. I thought that was interesting!